# Kafka connect with RabbitMQ sink

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-kafka-connect

I want to use Kafka connect in order to read events from Kafka topic and write them into RabbitMQ.
In order to do so, I need to use [the RabbitMQ sink](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-rabbitmq-sink/current/index.htm).

Each of the events coming from Kafka should be sent to a different queue (based on some field in the event structure), which means a different routing key should be used. As far as I know, there's an option to configure a static routing key in the sink configuration. Is there any option to configure it dynamically based on the events to achieve the required behavior?

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: @kissu I went through all the Kafka connect documentation and didn't find something that answers my needs. I know there's an option to write my own connector but I don't want to go there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Rabbit connector, but there is a ValueToKey Connect transformation, if that is what you need